# Sumar cantidades de un item traído de la base de datos en foreach con php

Tags: php, array, foreach

saludos estoy intentando realizar una suma de notas que las extraigo de mi bd pero el problema es que me esta concatenando los valores no me los esta sumando cabe destacar que el arreglo que me trae los datos los recorro en un Foreach y allí realizo la suma pero no tengo resultado alguno solo logro concatenar los valores y no comprendo porque.
este es mi código de como estoy ejecutando la suma

```
else{
$suma=0;
    foreach ($notaestudiante as $key => $nota) {
        if ($nota["Id_estudiante"]== $estudiante["Id"] AND $nota["Id_curso"]== $cursos["Id_curso"]) {
            var_dump($nota["Nota"]);
            $suma += $nota["Nota"];

            if ($nota["Estado"]=="Reprobado") {
            $pdf->SetTextColor(220,50,50);
            $pdf->Cell(37,10,$nota["Nota"],1,0,'C');
            $pdf->Cell(38,10,$nota["Estado"],1,0,'C');
            }
            if ($nota["Estado"]=="Aprobado") {
            $pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
            $pdf->Cell(37,10,$nota["Nota"],1,0,'C');
            $pdf->Cell(38,10,$nota["Estado"],1,0,'C');
            }
        }
    }
echo $suma;
}
```

Este es el resultado que obtengo[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

realice un var_dump de ese Item y me muestra lo siguiente,
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y por que no realizas la suma en la consulta?, creo que será mucho mas eficiente y te ahorras todo ese código

Comment: prueba haciendo `$suma += intval($nota["Nota"]);`

Comment: Agrega un var_dump() de $notaestudiante, para saber como traes los valores.

Comment: Lo intente de ambas maneras tanto con intval e (int) y tengo el mismo resultado. ahora bien agg el var_dump() y este fue el resultado, me trae los 3 arreglos. https://photos.app.goo.gl/KmGLSRTCvNcZsD9o8

Answer (score 1):

Creo que se podria solucionar convirtiendo el dato a entero

```php
...
foreach ($notaestudiante as $key => $nota) {
    if ($nota["Id_estudiante"]== $estudiante["Id"] AND $nota["Id_curso"]== $cursos["Id_curso"]) {
        var_dump($nota["Nota"]);
        $suma += intval($nota["Nota"]);
        ....
```

Comment: Ya lo intente de esa manera y también utilizando (int) me lo sigue concatenando de las 2 maneras